# Equal or higher multiple of a number, Python

Tags: python, numbers

I have been challenged with designing a code which validates a GTIN-8 code. I have looked on how to find the equal or higher multiple of a 10 and I have had no success so far, hope you guys can help me!

Here is a small piece of code, I need to find the equal or higher multiple of 10.

```
NewNumber = (NewGtin_1 + Gtin_2 + NewGtin_3 + Gtin_4 + NewGtin_5 + Gtin_6 + NewGtin_7)
print (NewNumber)
```

Comment: equal or higher multiple of 10 with respect to what number?

Comment: The code you show is useless to help understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean find the smallest multiple of 10 that is greater than or equal to your number, try

```
def round_up_by_10s(num):
    return -((-num) // 10) * 10
```

That works for positive and negative numbers, integer or float, in Python 2.x or Python 3.x. It also avoids an if statement and can be written as a one-liner. For a float number it returns a float: surround the return value with an `int(...)` if you want the returned value to always be an integer.

If you mean find the smallest number that is a multiple of your number and of 10, try

```
def lcm10(num):
    return (10 // gcd(num, 10)) *  num
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I did mean the smallest multiple of 10 that is greater than or equal to the number.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking You can find multiples with the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operation:

```
if number % 10 == 0:
  do something
```

Comment: this has helped me a little bit, however i need to find the number and then do something, the if statement isnt needed

Comment: @NScott but how do you plan to find that number if you dont check if it is a multiple of 10? Also, if I helped you, consider upvoting my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you what the smallest multiple of 10 that is higher or equal than NewNumber. If that's the case, do:

```
last_digit = NewNumber % 10
bigger = NewNumber - last_digit
if last_digit != 0:
   bigger += 10
```

Also, you shouldn't use capital letters to start variable names, those are usually used for classes only.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using this:

```
# method 1 for integers
n = NewNumber / 10 * 10
if n < NewNumber: n += 10
# method 2 for floats, decimals
import math
n = math.ceil(NewNumber / 10) * 10
```